# Load a single library from a specific location by default

Tags: linux, libraries

Recently I had an issue with any software that was complied to use `openssl3`. (For instance, [with FreeRDP](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/issues/7878).) The issue was caused by `Dell Command | Configure` which was packaged for `Ubuntu 18.04` but I had it installed on `Ubuntu 22.04`. The Dell software provided a version of `openssl` for which the rest of the `Ubuntu 22.04` was not compiled.

In some way which I am trying to understand with this question, the Dell provided `libcrypto` was loaded by default and used by all software in the environment, (hence my problem). How can the default location of a library be changed system-wide, per library, as it was apparently done by the Dell installation?

*I am already aware of `LD_PRELOAD` but it seems to be used to change the location of all shared libraries at runtime.*

*While I happen to be on Ubuntu, is there a non Ubuntu specific way to point to a default library location for a single library?*

Comment: Possibly related https://askubuntu.com/questions/350068/where-does-ubuntu-look-for-shared-libraries

Comment: This is related and useful too. I don't see that it's a complete fix though. In my case I had two versions of the same library. I'd like to know how to choose one rather than the other.